# SpringBoot 2 Actuator with Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

How do I make use of Spring Security for securing the actuator endpoints but not interfere with any of the other application URLs? The security mechanism in our application is handled by a different framework so I would like to disable Spring Security by default and only enabled for `/actuator/` endpoints.

To achieve this, I've added the following to the initialization class.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
```

With that, the Spring Security default configuration is disabled. After this, what changes do I need to make configure security for actuator endpoints?

Comment: Actuator endpoints are accessible via `EndpointRequest.class` you can apply your security policy from there. And I suggest you to let the security autoconfiguration and just customize it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use below code and configurations

application.properties

```
spring.security.user.name=user
spring.security.user.password=password
spring.security.user.roles=ENDPOINT_ADMIN
```

Securing Actuator endpoints

```
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.EndpointRequest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

/**
 * @author dpoddar
 *
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ActuatorSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to("health", "flyway","info")).permitAll()
        .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).hasRole("ENDPOINT_ADMIN")
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
            ;
    }

}
```

Comment: using this configuration, when I try to access "/actuator/hystrix.stream" I am prompted to sign in endlessly. I mean, if I enter correct user:password and hit ENTER I am prompted to sign in again... how can I debug basic auth?

Comment: Work for me. I create a sample on github with all CI/CD by Travis-ci: https://github.com/NoraUi/noraui-datas-webservices

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a separate context for the actuator anymore.

Assumption is that as long as the non-actuator endpoints just need no security restrictions the following configuration would work.

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).authenticated().anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and().formLogin();
    }
}
```

The `EndpointRequest` handles matching any `Actuator` endpoint, giving a form login for the sake of testing. Note that even `/info` and `/health` are secured. The `EndpointRequest` has more options for granularity; additionally in Spring Boot 2 only `info`, and `health` are enabled by default.

Or you could just secure the paths behind whatever security mechanism you are using for your other APIs

I pushed an example app here,

https://github.com/DarrenForsythe/secure-spring-actuator-only

Answer (score 0):

its work

```
package com.example.demo.config;

import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.EndpointRequest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).authenticated().anyRequest().permitAll().and()
                .httpBasic().and().csrf().disable()
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).